# Best/practical combination of SIM cards to use for a around the world trip?

Tags: cellphones

What SIM cards are recommended to provide mobile data at reasonable prices across lots of countries, in order to support traveling around the world?

For example. the [three](http://www.three.co.uk/Store/SIM/Plans_for_phones) network provides a one-month contract SIM that provides '[feel at home](http://www.three.co.uk/feel-at-home)' data roaming in 60 countries, including most of Europe, USA and Australia, for £13, which is amazing.

Are there any other cards covering South America, Asia, and Africa?

Comment: I have a "ChatSim" card I use when I travel. It provides unlimited "WhatsApp" messages (along with other textual chats). It costs just 10 euro/year. I think it's a good solution. It works worldwide AFAIK

Comment: Even if the three 'feel at home' offer look great in the ads, there are several reports on data speed being so severly throttled, that internet usage is practically impossible.

Comment: I have a Three UK SIM and can confirm the data is slow everywhere I've used it outside the UK. Also a contract SIM is going to require a UK address and payment method, so it isn't for everyone. My current favorite is Google Project Fi, which works in 130+ countries without intentional  throttling, but that requires a US address and payment method. The answer is hence going to depend somewhat on where your home is.

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of such SIM cards and their pricing changes weekly if not daily. Any answer posted here would become irrelevant within a year. Therefore closing this as a price-shopping question.